# Simulate Browser Resources Expansion Behavior With Python

Tags: python, html, http, scrapy, web-scraping

I'm looking for a way to simulate browser resources expansion behavior.

The flow I'm trying to address is the following:

- Access an initial URL (e.g. http://example.dmn/index.htm)
- Parse the html response received  (e.g. index.htm)
- Find the resources that a browser will fetch as a result of the index parsing, e.g.:

  - Images
  - Flash
  - Embedded videos/audio
  - Frames /iFrames
- Repeat the process recursively for each new resource found

I'm not expecting to follow links (href), only page resources that will be fetched automatically by a browser when the page is first accessed.

Do you have a suggestion how to preform this simulation?

Are there any Python projects/libraries that may help ?

Thanks

Comment: Does it need to deal with dynamic sites, e.g. with javascript that may apply rollover/other DHTML? If so, I doubt anything but a browser instance will be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to look at the [Windmill Testing Framework](http://www.getwindmill.com/) which allows you to write tests in Python for web apps.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [spider.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/spider.py/0.5), and [robotparser](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/robotparser/index.html).  Barring those doing what you want automatically, you can dig into the HTML soup yourself with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org).

It may not provide all the exact features you need, but can be easily extended to do so.